# Выполнение скрипта спустя некоторое время после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

Пробовал так, не получается, выполняется сразу:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #hideMe{
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #FF5555;
        }
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var opa=100;
    function ds(){
        setTimeout(hide(), 100000);
    }
    function hide(){
        opa=opa-1;
        document.getElementById('hideMe').style.opacity=opa/100;
        if(opa>0){
            setTimeout(hide,10);
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="ds();">
    <div id='hideMe'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: вы отличаете вызов функции и от её имени?

    setTimeout(hide, 100000);

Comment: Обнаружен острый велосепидизм :)

$(document).ready(function(){$('#hideMe').delay(100000).fadeOut(1000)});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внимательней читайте про `setTimeout`:

```
function ds(){
    setTimeout(hide, 100000); // не нужны скобки у hide()
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function start() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        hide() ;
    });

    /* 
    setTimeout(hide, 100);
    setTimeout('hide()', 100);
    */
}

function hide() {
    var hideElem = document.getElementById('hideMe');

    hideElem.style.opacity = (!hideElem.style.opacity) ? 1 : hideElem.style.opacity;

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        hideElem.style.opacity -= '0.1';

        if(hideElem.style.opacity <= 0){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }

    }, 30);
}
</script>
```

Comment: ещё сделать забыли

    var opacity = hideElem.style.opacity;

Comment: @Spectre да не, я сделал это, но по непонятным мне данным, не заработало =\ забил.

Answer (score -5):

функция setTimeout НЕ выполняется в цикле! Для этого используется замкнутое выражение

```
for (var i = opa; i<=0; i--) {
  (function () {
    var ii = i;
    setTimeout ( function () {
        hideMe.style.opacity = ii/100; //  hideMe = document.getElementById('hideMe')

   }, (ii+1)*10);  // здесь методом тыка подберешь число
  })();
}
```

Comment: так я рекурсией делаю

Comment: >функция setTimeout НЕ выполняется в цикле!

что зе бред? и где вы в вопросе цикл увидели?